# Dealing with failures of a web service running on multiple instances

Tags: load-balancing, failover

I'm building an app that will call a web service that has 2 identical instances, each running on a different server, with its own IP.

The app can call any service instance at any time, but sometimes it may have difficulties getting a response from one of them (because of a network failure or a problem with the instance).

What is the recommended way to make the app automatically stop using the problematic instance?

How can it get back to using the instance when it's online again?

Are there standard libraries or tools to help this kind of scenario?

Comment: Usually you would have a load balancer server that would direct the request to the two instances.  The client application should be connecting to the load balancer URI and should have no awareness of your two instances.  If one of the instances fails the load balancer would direct all traffic to the remaining instance until the failed instance was brought back up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a load balancer.

You app will have to connect to the LB and not to the web servers directly. LBs maintain status of each server they are configured with ( through timeout or explicit http status calls). They automatically disable traffic from the disconnected servers and enable it once the instance is back.

Later on you can add or remove instances based upon your requirements ( manual or auto-scaling ) without requiring any changes in your app.

HAProxy and Nginx are widely used for internet scale load balancing. Cloud providers also provides this as a service, you can use them if you are on cloud ( like AWS has elastic load balancing, Google Cloud has Load Balancing ).